# using spread / rest operator in map function generates error TS2700

Tags: typescript

I'm wanting to change the values of 2 items in an array of objects, while maintaining the other values in the data.  The function works when I serve my ionic app in testing, but I get this awful error that usually means it won't build later on:

```
[ng] Time: 1878ms
[ng] : Compiled successfully.
[ng]     
[ng]     ERROR in src/app/pages/admin/admin.page.ts:46:66 - error TS2700: Rest types may only be created from object types.
[ng]     
[ng]     46       this.eventSource = [...list].map(({ startTime, endTime, ...list }) => {
[ng]                                                                         ~~~~
```

I've looked at other posts about this, but it didn't help me.  Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

My code:

```
loadDbEVents() {
// get the list of appointments from the db
this.api.readAll('appts').subscribe((list: []) => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
  this.eventSource = [list].map(({ startTime, endTime, ...list }) => {
    // convert the start and end times to UTC so the calendar works
    return {
      startTime: this.dataService.convertDateToCalendarUtc(startTime),
      endTime: this.dataService.convertDateToCalendarUtc(endTime),
      ...list,
    };
  });
  console.log(this.eventSource);
});
```

}

Here is a screenshot of the data returned when I log this.eventSource to the console:
[image: Javascript console log with data example]

Comment: Can you check this out? 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gbwIYC4CMANDAEYHHAEC+hOuATMWUTJfjXQMxPmvUC6AbgBQw9ADpJiaP3EBbbAAcAFMpzFJ46VCoBKVAD5W4CCDgBTLSADmy7MW27dwmDCA

Comment: What is `list`? Btw spread in `[...list].map` is useless, also you're declaring `list` variable again in callback `({ startTime, endTime, ...list })` ...

Comment: sorry, list is the data that comes back from a subscribe() this is wrapped in.  I didn't want to clutter things with all the code.  It returns an array of objects like this: [{title:'this title', description: 'something', startTime: an_ISO_DATE_goes_here}, {title: 'that title', description: 'something', startTime: an_ISO_DATE_goes_here}].  I know I didn't need to use it within the brackets, but I was trying anything because I couldn't get it to work.  I'll update my post to include more code.

Comment: I actually tried doing it with [list].map, but it's giving me more type errors about startTime not being a part of it.  By doing it as [...list].map, that error goes away in the console and the page renders.

Comment: Did you actually try to build this code in production mode? Does the error still come up when you restart `ionic serve`? If the issue still persists it would be best if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to build as arcan mentioned, and still had problems.  I am using the ionic2-calendar, which requires the dates to be in a specific format.  I was attempting to use the spread/rest operators to modify the startTime and endTime to show local time, but did not want to lose the rest of the appointment or define each field (hence the spread / rest operators).

Here is what worked for me:

```
this.api.readAll('appts').subscribe((appts: Appt[]) => {
  const Appts = appts.map((appt) => {
    const { startTime, endTime, ...other } = appt;
    // change times to local UTC format for calendar
    return {
      startTime: this.dataService.convertToUTC(
        this.dataService.convertToLocalTime(startTime)),
      endTime: this.dataService.convertToUTC(
        this.dataService.convertToLocalTime(endTime)),
      ...other,
    };
  });
  this.eventSource = Appts;
  console.log(this.eventSource);
});
```

This worked to display things the same as it was (it was displaying correctly), but without the error.  this.eventSource is of type any[], so maybe that had a good bit to do with it.  I'm not sure, but here is what worked for anyone who had this issue.